# Wordpress Permalinks Kills Taxonomy.php Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've got a custom post type as well as a custom taxonomy. Here's the registration code for both:

```
register_post_type('parts', array(  'label' => 'Parts','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => true,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'parts'),'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('parts_categories',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Parts',
  'singular_name' => 'Part',
  'menu_name' => 'Parts',
  'add_new' => 'Add Part',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Part',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Part',
  'new_item' => 'New Part',
  'view' => 'View Part',
  'view_item' => 'View Part',
  'search_items' => 'Search Parts',
  'not_found' => 'No Parts Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Parts Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Part',
),) );


register_taxonomy('parts_categories',array (
  0 => 'parts',
),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Parts Categories','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'parts'),'singular_label' => 'Part Category') );
```

So everything works when permalinks are off:

- single-parts.php
- taxonomy-parts_categories.php
- archive-products.php

As soon as I turn permalinks ON, i get an Epic 404, ONLY for the page that SHOULD point to taxonomy-parts_categories.php

Both the single and archive page work. What's stranger is that the default taxonomy.php template doesn't even get picked up.

Htaccess is definitely in place, and i've flushed my rewrites to no avail. I've also toggled my permalinks on/off with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rewrite parameter on the register_taxonomy with slug => 'parts' that's the same slug as your post type.

Try changing it to something different, revisiting the permalink page (you don't need to change anything, just visiting the permalinks settings page will flush it) and try again.